# Get only numbers from the string in android

Tags: java, android

I have this string on `getSelectedItem()` of spinner I want just mobile number but it displaying with the name.

```
Spinner spinnerthree = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
String num=(String) spinnerthree.getSelectedItem();
```

return result is:

> return num=01111111111(abc)

Comment: you can use  `String.split(param)` string on the basis of `"("` then you will get only numbers at 0 index in String array. if `"("` is common in all strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex. 
A lot of examples can be found here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Select tab 'Community',  category 'Address and Phone'.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex, like @keaukraine suggested, here is how to implement:

```
Spinner spinnerthree = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
String num =(String) spinnerthree.getSelectedItem();  

Pattern intsOnly = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher makeMatch = intsOnly.matcher(num);
makeMatch.find();
String result = makeMatch.group();
Log.i("Pattern", result);
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Best of luck! As a side note, the above code I show expects an number in the `String`, you will get an exception if no number is present.